Fredholm map for a singular ODE problem

Let $C_{2l}^0(\mathbb{R}),C_{2l}^2(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Banach
space of $2l$-periodic $C^0(\mathbb{R}),C^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions
respectively. Define the open subsets \begin{align*}&U:=\{\mu\in C_{2l}^2(\mathbb{R}):\min_{\mathbb{R}}\mu>0\}\\& V:=\{\sigma\in C_{2l}^0(\mathbb{R}):||\sigma-\sigma^*||_\infty\leq r\}\end{align*} for fixed $\sigma^*\in C_{2l}^0(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\displaystyle\min_{\mathbb{R}}\sigma^*>0$ and $r>0$ small enough. Consider the map $F:U\times V\to C_{2l}^0(\mathbb{R})$ defined as
$$F(\mu,\sigma):=-\ddot{\mu}+\sigma\mu-\frac{c}\mu$$ for $c>0$. Prove that the map
$\mu\mapsto F(\mu,\sigma)$ for any $\sigma\in V$ is
a Fredholm map of index $0$.

I think that by standard argument by existence theorem of ODEs, kernel of $T:\mu\to F(\mu,\sigma)$ will be finite dimensional. But I have difficulty to find the cokernel of $T$ and thereby find its dimension. I know that index $0$ should imply $$\dim\ker(T)=\dim\text{coker}(T)$$ But I have no idea how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Maybe I am missing something... Is $\mu \mapsto F(\sigma, \mu)$ really linear?
